# Fail when decoding into a circe when JSON has more attributes than expected

Tags: json, scala, circe

I would like to capture JSON typos and other schema violations. I originally wanted to use `circe-json-schema` but the scala version provided in our execution environment is 2.11 which is not supported by said library. I turned to semi-automatic decoding but it, unfortunately, ignores any "additional" attributes in the incoming JSON. Example:

```scala
val json = json"""{ "pepe": "corre", "tito": "tira" }"""
case class Pepe(pepe: String)
implicit val pepeDecoder: Decoder[Pepe] = deriveDecoder

/* ideally, because "tito" is extra but the assertion nevertheless fails */
assert(json.as[Pepe] == Left("decoding failure"))
```

My other option would be to *manually* traverse the *whole* JSON w/ a `Map` of expectations but I think it pedestrian. If there are any other options w/in the **circe** world, including *coexisting* w/ a higher scala major version (in order to leverage `circe-json-schema`) w/in Maven, please advise.

Comment: There was a PR for this: https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/848
Maybe you find your solution in there